php warning for zmq in php
I try to use ZeroMQ ( zmq ) in my php (version 8.2.12)

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\zmq (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\zmq (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zmq.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_zmq.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zmq.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_zmq.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

WARN  PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\zmq (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0.

WARN  PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zmq.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_zmq.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0.

Hello I am new in this programming and I got some problem here, I tried using ZeroMQ ( zmq ) in my php to receive video form other device, but the other device using Python, flask, and ZeroMQ ( zmq ) to send the video.
Can you solve this problem and maybe I did wrong an installation of ZeroMQ ( zmq ) in php, can you tell me how to install it on Windows O/S?

I think zmq is available for 5.4 and 7.x as described here: https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows , but try to install the latest version, it may work
try to install php_zmq extension, and since you are using xampp, I think this may help:

Download: https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows
install the extension
make sure that you have php_zmq.dll in this directory C:\xampp\php\ext\
copy the libzmq.dll to the C:\xampp root directory, not the PHP
restart apache

